# How to get phone number in android programaticaly

Tags: java, android, telephonymanager

Can the primary phone number be obtained without the READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE permission?

I have been trying various methods to obtain a unique device ID that cannot be reset unless the device itself is changed (such as the IMEI), as required by my company. However, since Android Q, the READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE permission is required to obtain the IMEI number, so I had to skip that step. Instead, I am creating a unique ID by combining the phone number and model name.

However, when I tried to retrieve the phone number using the getLine1Number() method, I realized that it also requires the READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE permission, which is only accessible to Google apps and not third-party apps.

Here is how I implemented it:

```
punchin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                punchout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                punchin.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), phone_number, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
        punchout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                punchout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                punchin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), phone_number, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });


 // Function will run after click to button
    @SuppressLint("HardwareIds")
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    public void GetNumber(View v) {

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireContext(), READ_SMS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireContext(), READ_PHONE_NUMBERS) ==
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireContext(),
                READ_PHONE_STATE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Permission check

            // Create obj of TelephonyManager and ask for current telephone service
            TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) requireContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

            phone_number = telephonyManager.getLine1Number();
        } else {
            // Ask for permission
            requestPermission();
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private void requestPermission() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{READ_SMS, READ_PHONE_NUMBERS, READ_PHONE_STATE}, 100);
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("HardwareIds")
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 100:
                TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) requireContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireContext(), READ_SMS) !=
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireContext(),
                        READ_PHONE_NUMBERS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                        ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireContext(), READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return;
                }
                phone_number = telephonyManager.getLine1Number();

                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected value: " + requestCode);
        }
    }
```

Comment: No, the primary phone number cannot be obtained without the READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE permission. The READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE permission is a dangerous permission that allows an app to read the user's primary phone number, including the country code, without the user's consent. Starting from Android 10 (API level 29) and above, even system apps are not granted this permission by default.